# javascript action on table edit and delete button

Tags: javascript, php

i have a table with every row having a edit and a delete button.  Now what should i do to enable them meaning  the delete button the row will get deleted and the data from my database also ? the edit button also? can someone help?

Comment: You have lost the code I think!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using ajax. You have the table having the delete button for each row. you have to set row id on each delete button with click event. For example onClick="DeleteRow(Id)". Replace the Id with that particular row id.
Now create the javascript function deleterow. This function will call the php page using ajax. Send the row id to php page. write mysql delete query on php. The same process for edit functionality also.